# Convex optimization - bound on a subgradient

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

Consider the following optimization problem:
$$
\min_{b\in \mathbb{R}^d} \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i-x_i^{\top}b|.
$$
A text I'm reading states without a proof that
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{sgn}(y_i-x_i^{\top}b^*)x_i\right\|\le \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{y_i=x_i^{\top}b^*\}x_i\right\|,
$$
where $b^*$ minimizes the sum of absolute deviations. It there a way to prove the inequality? (I know that when the points ($y_i,x_i$) are distinct, $\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{y_i=x_i^{\top}b^*\}=d$.)

Comment: The thing you are summing over is a vector so what is meant by taking the absolute value?

Comment: @giorginguyen Oh, I meant a norm.

Comment: How do you define $\mathrm{sgn}(0)$?

Comment: @VHarisop It is not specified in the text. However, I belive it's 0.

Comment: This inequality seems trivial because the first-order optimality condition is simply $0 \in \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathrm{sgn}(y_i - x_i^\top b^{\star}) x_i$.

Comment: @VHarisop Could you elaborate?

Comment: Since the function is optimized at $b^{\star}$, the first-order optimality condition says  that $0$ is a subgradient of the objective function at $b^{\star}$. The subgradient of the absolute value function is $\mathrm{sgn}$, and therefore an application of the chain rule gives the expression I wrote above.

Comment: @VHarisop Right. It is indeed trivial. Thnx.